# Use format specifier with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

Tags: c#

This could be quite a straightforward question, I've tried find a answer but couldn't.

What I'm trying to do is to format my DateTimeOffset to use format specifier "G" and append timezone "zzz" with it. I like to use 'CurrentCulture' as well. 
myDateTimeOffset.ToString("G zzz", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)

However, I'm getting result like 'G +12:00'.

I'm expecting to get like '28/07/2016 3:36:31 PM +12'. 
Any advice to get it to format properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:G} {0:zzz}", myDateTimeOffset);
```